# Freelance visa in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom, freelance

I am an Indian citizen, currently doing a master's in Italy. I have 10 years experience in videography and video editing. I am looking for a freelance visa in the UK. May I know more details about the freelance visa and how to apply for this?

Answer (score 2):

You would need to apply for a [Tier 1 (Entrepreneur)](https://www.gov.uk/tier-1-entrepreneur) visa but for that

> You must have access to at least £50,000 investment funds to apply.

Closely related to: [Can I get a UK visa as self employed?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9248/can-i-get-a-uk-visa-as-self-employed)